# Best way to force textures upload to GPU at scene load time?

Tags: aframe

I was wondering the best way to force textures upload to GPU at scene load? I’ve read GPU Texture Preloading section within [Best Practices](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/introduction/best-practices.html#gpu-texture-preloading), but I’m not quite sure if that’s something that needs to be done texture by texture and element by element.

There's an old thread talking about it [here](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/3135), but it doesn't seem to have a happy ending so far :(

Would it make sense to make a traverse from the sceneEl, before the scene has loaded, obtain every texture and call `document.querySelector('a-scene').renderer.setTexture2D(eachTexture, 0)`?

Thanks

Comment: You have to call `setTexture2D` once per texture, not per entity. Are your textures coming from models, material component, somewhere else?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Thing is, how can I get each texture from each model/material component, before it's attached to each material, so I can call `setTexture2D` within my custom loading phase? (the idea is to preload every texture in a loading phase, and start the experience once everything was uploaded to the GPU in order to avoid those horrible seconds of ui-freeze)

Comment: Maybe listening to `materialtextureloaded` could help a bit?

Answer (score 1):

`setTexture2D` no longer exists as of r103. You can use something like this instead

```
  const forceTextureInitialization = function() {
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
    const geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry();
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.add(new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material));
    const camera = new THREE.Camera();

    return function forceTextureInitialization(texture) {
      material.map = texture;
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
    };
  }();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that makes sense to do.

Just call `sceneEl.renderer.setTexture2D(texture, i)`, passing in the three.js texture. And I think it's better to cycle `i` to a different value each call between 1 and 8.